# How to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); where i have to use these line for my error

Tags: java, android, android-adapter

ItemListBaseAdapter.java

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<Recipedetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

private Integer[] imgid = {
        R.drawable.vegeterian,
        R.drawable.nonveg,
        R.drawable.pickels,
        R.drawable.soup,
        R.drawable.sweets,
        R.drawable.cakes,
        R.drawable.icecreams,
        R.drawable.chinesevegdishes,
        R.drawable.chinesenonveg,
        R.drawable.chinesenoodles,
        R.drawable.chinesesoup,
        R.drawable.godhumaivegadai,
        R.drawable.soyamorekoozh,
        R.drawable.tomatokulambu,
        R.drawable.tomatoupma,
        R.drawable.vadanavratrispecial,
        R.drawable.eggkurma,
        R.drawable.milagu,
        R.drawable.rasam,
        R.drawable.vegetablekootu,
        R.drawable.avial,
        R.drawable.kothavarangaicurry,
        R.drawable.allepeyfishcurry,
        R.drawable.spicymadraschicken,
        R.drawable.prawns,
        R.drawable.keralachickenstew,
        R.drawable.nilgirichickenkorma,
        R.drawable.pepperchickencurry,
        R.drawable.chettiandchicken,
        R.drawable.prawnmasala,
        R.drawable.beeffry,
        R.drawable.crispyfish,
        R.drawable.amlapickle,
        R.drawable.avakaipickle,
        R.drawable.capsicumpickle,
        R.drawable.lemonpickle,
        R.drawable.onionpickle,
        R.drawable.mangopickle,
        R.drawable.tendermangopickle,
        R.drawable.tomatopickle,
        R.drawable.chillipickles,
        R.drawable.gingerpickle,
        R.drawable.garlicsoup,
        R.drawable.mixedvegsoup,
        R.drawable.chickenmanchowsoup,
        R.drawable.cleartomatosoup,
        R.drawable.sweetcornvegetablesoup,
        R.drawable.prawnandnoodlesoup,
        R.drawable.beetrootsoup,
        R.drawable.capsicumsoup,
        R.drawable.muttonsoup,
        R.drawable.spinachsoup,
        R.drawable.vegcurry,
        R.drawable.mushroommutter,
        R.drawable.alooparatha,
        R.drawable.daltadka,
        R.drawable.aloomethi,
        R.drawable.rajma,
        R.drawable.paneerbhujri,
        R.drawable.alooghobi,
        R.drawable.aloosabzi,
        R.drawable.kadhaipaneer,
        R.drawable.chickenwithbellpeppers,
        R.drawable.butterchicken,
        R.drawable.fishkorma,
        R.drawable.prawnfry,
        R.drawable.tandoorichicken,
        R.drawable.maccherjholfish,
        R.drawable.shamikabab,
        R.drawable.saagmeat,
        R.drawable.sindhichickenbiryani,
        R.drawable.punjabichickencurry,
        R.drawable.gulabjamun,
        R.drawable.basundi,
        R.drawable.peda,
        R.drawable.badhamhalwa,
        R.drawable.coconutburfi,
        R.drawable.kulfi,
        R.drawable.ladoo,
        R.drawable.mysorepak,
        R.drawable.ricekheer,
        R.drawable.badam,
        R.drawable.cauliflowersoup,
        R.drawable.cucumbersoup,
        R.drawable.tomatosoup,
        R.drawable.mulligatawnysoup,
        R.drawable.greenpeassoup,
        R.drawable.northindianmuttonsoup,
        R.drawable.chickennoodlesoup,
        R.drawable.spicybeansoup,
        R.drawable.eggdropsoup,
        R.drawable.springvegsoup,
        R.drawable.mushroomandseitan,
        R.drawable.tofuwith3spices,
        R.drawable.creamyvegpie,
        R.drawable.grilledvegmedley,
        R.drawable.bakedsquash,
        R.drawable.africanchickenstew,
        R.drawable.westafricanchicken,
        R.drawable.africanyamsoup,
        R.drawable.chickenchilliroast,
        R.drawable.chilliblackbeans,
        R.drawable.williecake,
        R.drawable.pumpkingingercupcakes,
        R.drawable.doublelayerpumpkincheesecake,
        R.drawable.carrotcake,
        R.drawable.sexcake,
        R.drawable.chocolatechipicecream,
        R.drawable.cookieicecream,
        R.drawable.cinnamonicecream,
        R.drawable.appleicecream,
        R.drawable.walnut,
        R.drawable.chineseaubergins,
        R.drawable.spicycucumber,
        R.drawable.chinesemushrooms,
        R.drawable.chinesegobi,
        R.drawable.spicytofu,
        R.drawable.chinesetilchicken,
        R.drawable.chickenmoongali,
        R.drawable.sweetsourchicken,
        R.drawable.cherrychicken,
        R.drawable.mymasalachicken,
        R.drawable.coldseasamenoodles,
        R.drawable.sobanoodles,
        R.drawable.noodleswithtofu,
        R.drawable.chinesevegandbeef,
        R.drawable.noodleswithpepper,
        R.drawable.jhingasoup,
        R.drawable.masalachickensoup,
        R.drawable.cabbagesoup,
        R.drawable.chinesepumpkinsoup,
        R.drawable.baconsoup,





        };



private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipedetails> results) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = results;
    l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
        holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
        holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
    holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
    return convertView;
}
public synchronized   void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
    itemDetailsrrayList.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txt_itemName;
    TextView txt_itemDescription;
    ImageView itemImage;
}

}
```

Recipedetails.java

```
public class Recipedetails {

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getItemDescription() {
    return itemDescription;
}
public void setItemDescription(String itemDescription) {
    this.itemDescription = itemDescription;
}


public int getImageNumber() {
    return imageNumber;
}
public void setImageNumber(int imageNumber) {
    this.imageNumber = imageNumber;
}

private String name ;
private String itemDescription;
private int imageNumber;
}
```

Listview.java

```
public class SouthIndian  extends Activity {
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = GetSearchResults();

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details));

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 //final ArrayList<Recipedetails> act = GetSearchResults(); 
                //if (act != null)


                switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                {
                    case 1:
                         Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                 AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);     
                        startActivity(new1Activity);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity2.class);     
                        startActivity(new2Activity);
                        break; 

                    case 4:
                        Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity3.class);     
                        startActivity(new3Activity);
                        break;      

                   default:
                       Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } 
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {


                    ItemListBaseAdapter.refreshAdapter(item);
                    //ItemListBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Pickels");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);




        return results;
    }
}
```

and my log cat error is

```
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed 
but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a 
background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) 
with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]

03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1544)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3403)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7239)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2168)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1903)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2174)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1917)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1953)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1405)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2410)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1901)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7419)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3220)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3165)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4292)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4271)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4363)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:179)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
03-19 05:04:35.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1110):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
```

In my code, how and where to use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`
**clicking the second item in the listview,application has stopped and showing error like this as i mention in logcat**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this method to your adapter

```
public synchronized void refresAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
    itemDetailsrrayList.addAll(items);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then make this call from where you want to refresh your adapter

```
final Activity act = getActivity(); //only neccessary if you use fragments
if (act != null)
    act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            yourAdapter.refreshAdapter(item);
        }
    });
```

this should solve your problem

Comment: ,i am having lots of list view,i have to add in all list view.?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HmWkA2f2 can you look at my code in this link,and tell me where i want to add the second code you mention above

Comment: sorry here not coming this issue,in southindia.java only if i click the first item in an listview it will works again if i return and i click the anotheritem in that listview,activity has satopped.  http://pastebin.com/CxTZHjED  see this code

Comment: where i have to use the second code as i mention before http://pastebin.com/CxTZHjED

Comment: You will have to give your adapter global scope for your activities and then where you want the data of the adapter to update call youradapter.refresh(with your new list as parameter); as I showed above

Comment: ,i cant understand correctly,can you edit my code and tell me,how do that one,i am new to android

Comment: the problem showing in listadapter and soutindian.java http://pastebin.com/CxTZHjED,can you look at my code and tell me

Comment: Here is a new version that I changed. I did not test it just have a look at what I did and use that as reference http://pastebin.com/u7dny5Dn please try out the rest yourself

Comment: ,you gave two code in an above,first code i put in my Itemlistadapter,i want where to put the second code in southindia.java,final Activity act = getActivity(); these code

Comment: I see I did not add my second part of the code, the runOnUiThread method. Try adding that.

Comment: I can't do your code for you! Here on this line in the change I made, refreshYourAdapter(getSearchResults()); add the runOnUiThread around it.

Comment: both should be come only in soutindian.java or first part  comes in Itemlistbaseadapter?

Comment: The first part comes in your adapter and the second part in your activity. Look at the variables defined in the code I posted in the answer.

Comment: act.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  it showing error in this line and the last line of item error showing is The method runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){}) is undefined for the type 
  ArrayList<Recipedetails>

Comment: please update your code in the question so that we can see what you did

Comment: i update my code,can you see above of my question,i also added what you put your answer code

Comment: its showing error in ItemListBaseAdapter.refreshAdapter(item); item has problem

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is... Are you using this runOnUiThread?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26450/discussion-between-neil-and-kkarthickk)

Comment: ,can you see that,whats the problem behind that one

Answer (score 0):

Don't have `itemDetailsrrayList` as `static`.

Comment: I dont get it fully from you,can you tell,what i want to do

Comment: Currently every time you create a new Adapter you're replacing the content of every instance. Remove the static keyword to stop the instances from sharing one list.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/CxTZHjED this java file and listadapter showing problem,how to do