# Error :The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification

Tags: java, android

This is my logcat erro;

```
03-20 04:24:42.482: E/AndroidRuntime(920): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]
```

I put all the possible ways,but once again its showing the error again and again
ItemListAdapter.java what i added for these problem is

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<Recipedetails> itemDetailsrrayList;

private Integer[] imgid = {
                R.drawable.vegeterian,
                R.drawable.nonveg,
                R.drawable.pickels,
                R.drawable.soup,
                R.drawable.sweets,
                R.drawable.cakes,
                R.drawable.icecreams,
                R.drawable.chinesevegdishes,
                R.drawable.chinesenonveg,
                R.drawable.chinesenoodles,
                R.drawable.chinesesoup,
                R.drawable.godhumaivegadai,
                R.drawable.soyamorekoozh,
                R.drawable.tomatokulambu,
                R.drawable.tomatoupma,
                R.drawable.vadanavratrispecial,
                R.drawable.eggkurma,
                R.drawable.milagu,
                R.drawable.rasam,
                R.drawable.vegetablekootu,
                R.drawable.avial,
                R.drawable.kothavarangaicurry,
                R.drawable.allepeyfishcurry,
                R.drawable.spicymadraschicken,
                R.drawable.prawns,
                R.drawable.keralachickenstew,
                R.drawable.nilgirichickenkorma,
                R.drawable.pepperchickencurry,
                R.drawable.chettiandchicken,
                R.drawable.prawnmasala,
                R.drawable.beeffry,
                R.drawable.crispyfish,
                R.drawable.amlapickle,
                R.drawable.avakaipickle,
                R.drawable.capsicumpickle,
                R.drawable.lemonpickle,
                R.drawable.onionpickle,
                R.drawable.mangopickle,
                R.drawable.tendermangopickle,
                R.drawable.tomatopickle,
                R.drawable.chillipickles,
                R.drawable.gingerpickle,
                R.drawable.garlicsoup,
                R.drawable.mixedvegsoup,
                R.drawable.chickenmanchowsoup,
                R.drawable.cleartomatosoup,
                R.drawable.sweetcornvegetablesoup,
                R.drawable.prawnandnoodlesoup,
                R.drawable.beetrootsoup,
                R.drawable.capsicumsoup,
                R.drawable.muttonsoup,
                R.drawable.spinachsoup,
                R.drawable.vegcurry,
                R.drawable.mushroommutter,
                R.drawable.alooparatha,
                R.drawable.daltadka,
                R.drawable.aloomethi,
                R.drawable.rajma,
                R.drawable.paneerbhujri,
                R.drawable.alooghobi,
                R.drawable.aloosabzi,
                R.drawable.kadhaipaneer,
                R.drawable.chickenwithbellpeppers,
                R.drawable.butterchicken,
                R.drawable.fishkorma,
                R.drawable.prawnfry,
                R.drawable.tandoorichicken,
                R.drawable.maccherjholfish,
                R.drawable.shamikabab,
                R.drawable.saagmeat,
                R.drawable.sindhichickenbiryani,
                R.drawable.punjabichickencurry,
                R.drawable.gulabjamun,
                R.drawable.basundi,
                R.drawable.peda,
                R.drawable.badhamhalwa,
                R.drawable.coconutburfi,
                R.drawable.kulfi,
                R.drawable.ladoo,
                R.drawable.mysorepak,
                R.drawable.ricekheer,
                R.drawable.badam,
                R.drawable.cauliflowersoup,
                R.drawable.cucumbersoup,
                R.drawable.tomatosoup,
                R.drawable.mulligatawnysoup,
                R.drawable.greenpeassoup,
                R.drawable.northindianmuttonsoup,
                R.drawable.chickennoodlesoup,
                R.drawable.spicybeansoup,
                R.drawable.eggdropsoup,
                R.drawable.springvegsoup,
                R.drawable.mushroomandseitan,
                R.drawable.tofuwith3spices,
                R.drawable.creamyvegpie,
                R.drawable.grilledvegmedley,
                R.drawable.bakedsquash,
                R.drawable.africanchickenstew,
                R.drawable.westafricanchicken,
                R.drawable.africanyamsoup,
                R.drawable.chickenchilliroast,
                R.drawable.chilliblackbeans,
                R.drawable.williecake,
                R.drawable.pumpkingingercupcakes,
                R.drawable.doublelayerpumpkincheesecake,
                R.drawable.carrotcake,
                R.drawable.sexcake,
                R.drawable.chocolatechipicecream,
                R.drawable.cookieicecream,
                R.drawable.cinnamonicecream,
                R.drawable.appleicecream,
                R.drawable.walnut,
                R.drawable.chineseaubergins,
                R.drawable.spicycucumber,
                R.drawable.chinesemushrooms,
                R.drawable.chinesegobi,
                R.drawable.spicytofu,
                R.drawable.chinesetilchicken,
                R.drawable.chickenmoongali,
                R.drawable.sweetsourchicken,
                R.drawable.cherrychicken,
                R.drawable.mymasalachicken,
                R.drawable.coldseasamenoodles,
                R.drawable.sobanoodles,
                R.drawable.noodleswithtofu,
                R.drawable.chinesevegandbeef,
                R.drawable.noodleswithpepper,
                R.drawable.jhingasoup,
                R.drawable.masalachickensoup,
                R.drawable.cabbagesoup,
                R.drawable.chinesepumpkinsoup,
                R.drawable.baconsoup,


                };



private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Recipedetails> results) {
        itemDetailsrrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
        return itemDetailsrrayList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_details_view, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txt_itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
                holder.txt_itemDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemDescription);
                holder.itemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.photo);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txt_itemName.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getName());
        holder.txt_itemDescription.setText(itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getItemDescription());
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(imgid[itemDetailsrrayList.get(position).getImageNumber() - 1]);
        return convertView;
}
public synchronized   void refreshAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    //itemDetailsrrayList.clear();
    itemDetailsrrayList = items;
   notifyDataSetChanged();
}

static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txt_itemName;
        TextView txt_itemDescription;
        ImageView itemImage;
}
```

}

My listactivity.java,these lines are added

public class NorthIndian  extends Activity {
     ItemListBaseAdapter _itemListAdapter;

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) { 
                Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                Toast.makeText(NorthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " + obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                {
                    case 1:
                         Intent newActivity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                 AndroidTabLayoutActivity4.class);     
                         startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent new1Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity5.class);     
                        startActivity(new1Activity);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        Intent new2Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity6.class);     
                        startActivity(new2Activity);
                        break; 

                    case 4:
                        Intent new3Activity = new Intent(NorthIndian.this, 
                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity7.class);     
                        startActivity(new3Activity);
                        break;      

                   default:
                       Toast.makeText(NorthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }  
        });

        refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
 }
 private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
     //this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
             _itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(items);
         }
     });
}


    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
        item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Sweets");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Tasty sweets made from indians");
        item_details.setImageNumber(5);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
        item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);




        return results;
    }
```

}

and southindina.java

```
ublic class SouthIndian extends Activity {
ItemListBaseAdapter _itemListAdapter;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);

        final ListView lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                        Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                        Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " +      obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        switch(obj_itemDetails.getImageNumber())
                        {
                            case 1:
                                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                 AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);    
                     startActivity(newActivity);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);    
                            startActivity(new1Activity);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity2.class);    
                            startActivity(new2Activity);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,
                                                AndroidTabLayoutActivity3.class);    
                            startActivity(new3Activity);
                                break;        

                           default:
                                   Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                }
        });

        refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
    }

    // THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE MORE OR LESS. THIS IS AS MUCH AS I CAN HELP

    private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
         //this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 _itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(items);
             }
         });
    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();

        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
            item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Pickels");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
            item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);

        return results;
    }
```

}

After adding all the links in my application the same problem coming again and again

see my code here for further clarification http://pastebin.com/DXdvB5HC

AndroidTabLayoutActivity

```
public class AndroidTabLayoutActivity extends TabActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabmain);

        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        // Tab for Photos
        TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Manual");
        photospec.setIndicator("Manual", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_photos_tab));
        Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, SouthIndianvegrecipes1.class);
        photospec.setContent(photosIntent);


        // Tab for Videos
        TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Videos");
        videospec.setIndicator("Videos", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_videos_tab));
        Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, SouthIndianvegrecipes.class);
        videospec.setContent(videosIntent);

        // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
        tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
         // Adding songs tab 
        tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
    }
}
```

Comment: Do You have ArrayAdapter? How itemDetailsrrayList is used in Your adapter?

Comment: @smk can you tell hot to do that one

Comment: @sandrstar See my code here http://pastebin.com/DXdvB5HC

Comment: Dudes ,can you look at my code and tell the solution, of that one,i am trying to solve two day,i cant get the solution of my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your existing class with this

```
public class SouthIndian extends Activity {
ItemListBaseAdapter _itemListAdapter;
ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();           
Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
ArrayList<Recipedetails> image_details = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();
ListView lv1;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        lv1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listV_main);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

                        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();
                        item_details = results.get(position);
                        //Object o = lv1.getItemAtPosition(position);

                      //  Recipedetails obj_itemDetails = (Recipedetails)o;
                        //Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " +      obj_itemDetails.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "You have chosen : " + " " +      item_details.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        switch(item_details.getImageNumber())
                        {
                            case 1:
                                 Intent newActivity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);    
                                 startActivity(newActivity);
                                break;

                            case 2:
                                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);    
                                startActivity(new1Activity);
                                break;

                            case 3:
                                Intent new2Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity2.class);    
                                startActivity(new2Activity);
                                break;

                            case 4:
                                Intent new3Activity = new Intent(SouthIndian.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity3.class);    
                                startActivity(new3Activity);
                                break;        

                           default:
                                   Toast.makeText(SouthIndian.this, "Wrong Input", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                }
        });


    }

    // THIS IS WHAT IT SHOULD LOOK LIKE MORE OR LESS. THIS IS AS MUCH AS I CAN HELP

    private void refreshYourAdapter(final ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
         //this is what I meant. The error clearly states you are not updating the adapter on the UI thread
         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 _itemListAdapter.refreshAdapter(items);
             }
         });
    }

    private ArrayList<Recipedetails> GetSearchResults(){
        /*ArrayList<Recipedetails> results = new ArrayList<Recipedetails>();           
        Recipedetails item_details = new Recipedetails();*/

        item_details.setName("Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Recipes made by raw materials");
            item_details.setImageNumber(1);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Non-Vegterian");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Flesh of sweet animals");
        item_details.setImageNumber(2);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Pickels");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Touchable dish  by Homemade");
        item_details.setImageNumber(3);
        results.add(item_details);

        item_details = new Recipedetails();
        item_details.setName("Soups");
        item_details.setItemDescription("Startup for our food");
            item_details.setImageNumber(4);
        results.add(item_details);

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        _itemListAdapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, image_details);
        refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
        lv1.setAdapter(_itemListAdapter);

    }
```

}

for more details to notify data [see Here](http://androidadapternotifiydatasetchanged.blogspot.in/)

Comment: now its not displaying my listview also

Comment: ok try like _itemListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: i put that code in my listview in oncreate function its not shoiwng my listview also now

Comment: where i want to put that one in which line

Comment: make sure you r adpter is fill all the data very well

Comment: is that any kind  of errore in Adpter Binding ?

Comment: before my listview shows all the items in an listview,after adding this code only its not displaying,can you look at my full code above

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26515/discussion-between-ankitmakwana-and-kkarthickk)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm not sure if it's forth it to change adapter in `onCreate()` right after it was set to the list. As per my understanding, You can create adapter with the right data from the beginning. E.g. **just for test** You could do it the following way:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                refreshYourAdapter(GetSearchResults());
            }
        }, 1000);
```

I would suggest to try the following changes (however, I wasn't able to run Your code completely):

ItemListBaseAdapter.java:

```
...
public synchronized void refreshYourAdapter(ArrayList<Recipedetails> items) {
    itemDetailsrrayList = items;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
...
```

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iKJuk1i9 i put like this,its not showing my listveiw right now

Comment: what code i want to write in refresh adapter in listview, http://pastebin.com/iKJuk1i9

Comment: checkout http://pastebin.com/xLewfk9e

Comment: @sanrstar,its  also not working

Comment: 03-20 06:22:49.402: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1921): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]

Comment: thats the above error showing in my logcat,i put all the possible what you said

Comment: i am having an listview with southindian and northindian,in that list 4 categories is there,veg and nonveg,sweet and soups,first time if i click the veg it will goes to the function and works nice,if again i come back and if i click the nonveg,it will shows my apps has stopped

Comment: i updated android tablayout activity also,can i send my coding to you,you can see my full code

Comment: yes how can i solve these problem

Comment: how to solve these issue,can you see my full code and tell

Comment: Dude wt hpnd,can you find something

Comment: Please, update Your question with actual data (including exception information) and remove above comments, because there's too many of them.

Comment: can you look at my code and tell the solution

Comment: did you look at my code,what about the solution,have you got any solution

Comment: Please, provide clear question and request for solution only after that. In Your question I see no work with the adapter in onClick(), so per my understanding there's no point to have the IllegalStateException in onClick as You described above, so I tret the question as invalid.

Comment: i have one listview,if i click the first item in the listview ,it will goes to their respective pages,after comeback agian,if we click the item in the list,my application has stopped

Comment: i have pasted all the requirements needed in my question.its showing error in logcat like 03-20 06:22:49.402: E/MessageQueue-JNI(1921): java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(2131165193, class android.widget.ListView) with Adapter(class com.example.recipestutors.ItemListBaseAdapter)]

Comment: Have You tried to remove 'static' from itemDetailsrrayList in ItemListBaseAdapter class?

Comment: how i have to remove,and how to do in my array list adapter

Comment: like this http://pastebin.com/mfhrneTn

Comment: can i send my code to you,it will clearly understood you

Comment: Dude i willl check and tell

Comment: Dude really thanks to you very much

Comment: Did it work? If so, then please, accept answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491876/how-to-use-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-where-i-have-to-use-these-line-for-my also.