# Multiple consecutive adapter notifyDataSetChanged calls do not refresh ListView

Tags: android, listview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

This is a very very serious buggy behavior and I have NO idea why this does not work.

My Adapter (extending `BaseAdapter`) combines two independent types of data. One is a cursor, the other takes a list of elements. Setters for both take the data and force `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
 public void setInformationsCursor(final Cursor newCursor) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setInformationsCursor called");
    if (newCursor == informationsCursor) {
        return;
    }
    informationsCursor = newCursor;

    // work on cursor here to extract data

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void setRides(final List<Ride> newRideList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setRides called");
    rideList = newRideList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

The data for these elements is gathered using two independent `AsyncTaskLoader` using the Loader framework.
More specificly, these setters are called from the corresponding `LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished` methods.

When the user chooses to display different data, both Loaders are fired in my `Fragment`:

```
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(RIDE_LOADER_ID, args, rideLoaderCallbacks);
getLoaderManager().restartLoader(INFORMATION_LOADER_ID, args, informationLoaderCallbacks);
```

To visualize the redraw of the `ListView`, I log within the adapter's `getView` method.

On my main development device running Android 4.3, everything works as expected.

1) User triggers change
2) Both loaders fire
3) The two loaders finish independently, each firing `notifyDataSetChanged` and I see lots of `getView` log output, but important: after the second loader finishes, the list is redrawn again.

Schematically:

- trigger loader 1
- trigger loader 2
- loader 1 finished
- notifyDataSetChanged from loader 1
- getView pos 1 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- getView pos 2 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- getView pos 3 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- loader 2 finished
- getView pos 4 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- notifyDataSetChanged fron loader 2
- getView pos 5 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- getView pos 1 (reflecting the changes from loader 2's data)
- getView pos 2 (reflecting the changes from loader 2's data)
- getView pos 3 (reflecting the changes from loader 2's data)
- getView pos 4 (reflecting the changes from loader 2's data)
- getView pos 5 (reflecting the changes from loader 2's data)

The list displays the new information just fine.

But now, I cannot believe this. On Android 4.2 the following happens:

- trigger loader 1
- trigger loader 2
- loader 1 finished
- notifyDataSetChanged from loader 1
- getView pos 1 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- getView pos 2 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- getView pos 3 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- loader 2 finished
- getView pos 4 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- notifyDataSetChanged from loader 2
- getView pos 5 (reflecting the changes from loader 1's data)
- THE END - no more getViews that should reflect the second loader's notifyDataSetChanged!

I hope this is more clear to you.

My assumption on notifyDataSetChanged always called on the UI thread is: each time I call it, it MUST force a redraw of all elements.
But this does not happen.

Comment: add some code where you alter list contents and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: How do you refresh the adapter data? Please show some code. I gave a answer here maybe it helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491876/how-to-use-adapter-notifydatasetchanged-where-i-have-to-use-these-line-for-my/15492143#15492143

Comment: Are you sure? My application which uses notifyDataSetChanged works well in Android 4.2. Post the code and make sure you update the list

Comment: dont you think that more likely it could be your fault? post some code of. your adapter

Comment: @Zordid can you put your code to your question, because maybe I can pu extra things to it,

Comment: Use notifyDataSetChanged on the UI thread.

Comment: @pskink: no, not my fault. You're very helpful, thanks.

Comment: notifyDataSetChanged is always called on the UI thread because it gets called from LoaderCallbacks.onLoadFinished which itself runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @Zordid without any code every answer will be like reading the crystall ball

Comment: Code is there. As you can see: it all boils down to consecutive calls to notifyDataSetChanged on the UI thread where on Android 4.2 this does NOT lead to refreshing the list correctly on the second call.

Comment: @Zordid based on that fragmentary code may i ask why dont you use a SimpleCursorAdapter ?

Comment: I got a cursor and a list of other elements... the combination of both is displayed in the ListView. How is that going to work with a SimpleCursorAdapter? It's not simple, it's combined. That's why I use my own Adapter. I adhere to all standards both in the use of Loaders and Adapters. But it does not work....

Comment: @Zordid i dont know the details but CursorWrapper could easly help you

Comment: Psink, it's nice but that is not the direction I got troubles with. My problem boils down to: if I call notifyDataSetChanged multiple times in a row, why only on Android 4.2 compared to 4.3/4.4 it does not trigger the ListViews refresh for each call.

Comment: i have no idea, you could run some "git diff" on 4.1 and 4.2 source tree but i dont think it is gonna help much

Comment: @Zordid as you didnt post your adapter code this will be wild guess but does it return true in hasStableIds() ?

Comment: It does not have stable IDs. But that's not the point... :-)

Comment: thats why i said its a wild guess

Comment: were you able to figure this out?